# Upper bound on the pdf of projected log-concave distribution on unit sphere

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $\mathbf X : \Omega \to \mathbb R^d$ be a random vector following a zero mean, identity covariance log-concave distribution.

Is there any known upper bound for the probability density function of $\mathbf X/\lVert\mathbf X \rVert_2$?